# how to use nuodb database in yii framework application?

Tags: php, yii, nuodb

Please let me know how can I user nuodb which is new for me in the YII framework .

my config/main.php

```
'db'=>array('connectionString' => 'nuodb:host=localhost:8080;dbname=getbusy'
```

and the user name in the databse is:

```
username=root
password=123456
```

Is this ok?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend this guide:

http://www.nuodb.com/techblog/2013/04/23/nuodb-how-to-turn-lamp-into-a-powerful-scale-out-software-bundle/

The connection string in the above code looks wrong, if you've installed nuodb for php correctly your connection string should look something (but not exactly) like:

```
'db'=>array('connectionString' => "nuodb:database=getbusy@localhost"
```